# React native swiper with parallax

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parallax, react-native-swiper

Is there a way to combine the [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) with the [react-naitve-parallax-scroll-view](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-parallax-scroll-view). I want to render pagination of swiper component in foreground component of parallax scroll. By default pagination of react native swiper have fixed position and when I scroll pagination stays on screen. I want to have parallax effect with pagination when scroll down to hide it. Pagination should be in renderForeground of parallax scroll view.

```
<Swiper 
    showsButtons={false}
    loop={false}
    showsPagination={true}
 >

    <ParallaxScrollView
           backgroundColor="transparent"
           contentBackgroundColor="#fff"
           parallaxHeaderHeight={250}
           renderBackground={() => (
                <ImageBackground 
                                source={require('../assets/images/image1.png')}
                                style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
                            />
                        )}
           renderForeground={() => (
                  <View style={{flex: 1,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                      <Text>Hello world</Text>     
                   </View>
                    )}>

                   <View style={{ height: 500 }}>
                       <Text>Scroll me</Text>
                    </View>
       </ParallaxScrollView>  
       <ParallaxScrollView
           backgroundColor="transparent"
           contentBackgroundColor="#fff"
           parallaxHeaderHeight={250}
           renderBackground={() => (
                <ImageBackground 
                                source={require('../assets/images/image1.png')}
                                style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
                            />
                        )}
           renderForeground={() => (
                  <View style={{flex: 1,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                      <Text>Hello world</Text>     
                   </View>
                    )}>

                   <View style={{ height: 500 }}>
                       <Text>Scroll me</Text>
                    </View>
       </ParallaxScrollView>  
</Swiper>
```

I found [react-native-pagination](https://github.com/garrettmac/react-native-pagination) but don't know how implement with this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this

https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel

this carousel provides the both Parallax and full page Swiper in a single component . it is best , its help me

Answer (score -1):

Tried with both the component. You want something like this.
https://snack.expo.io/r1NOE_q-Q

Comment: I need to swipe the whole page, for example, first slide is movie slide, second music and etc.

Comment: Update the code ...can you check now
Link: https://snack.expo.io/ry7UOkhZ7